# Android in app billing error:"error processing purchase bm-cch-17"

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am trying to add the functionality on "**android in app billing**" in my android apps.All method and functionality are okay and it work well for some android device.But it does not work well in my client device when he test the apps then he got a error.The error are "**error processing purchase bm-cch-17**".For checking the problem i also test it another my device the i got the error.But now yet i can not able to solve the problem.I also shared a screenshot which i get the error.

[image]

Please help to me how i can solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your google wallet settings.
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/wallet/hJNGInC9m3I%5B1-25-true%5D

Answer (score 0):

Go to your settings then google, remove one of your email account s by simply clicking on it than it gives you an option to remove account, then it has to work 100% sure.